# Looping file contents line by line in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a file called installer.txt which will contain a line by line of URLs of .tar.gz files like:

```
http://oscargodson.com/projects/example1.tar.gz
http://oscargodson.com/projects/anotherexample.tar.gz
http://oscargodson.com/projects/onemore.tar.gz
```

And I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
file = `cat installs.txt`
for word in file; do
  echo $word
done
```

But my output is like:

```
Oscars-MacBook-Air:Desktop oscargodson$ ./test.sh
=:                                                     cannot open `=' (No such file or directory)
http://oscargodson.com/projects/example1.tar.gz:       cannot open `http://oscargodson.com/projects/example1.tar.gz' (No such file or directory)
http://oscargodson.com/projects/anotherexample.tar.gz: cannot open `http://oscargodson.com/projects/anotherexample.tar.gz' (No such file or directory)
http://oscargodson.com/projects/onemore.tar.gz:        cannot open `http://oscargodson.com/projects/onemore.tar.gz' (No such file or directory)
file
```

It should output each line, or, so i thought. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You errors are actually being generated by the assignment statement. You cant have spaces around your assignment. And its good practice to always quote the rhs. So what you want is

```
#!/bin/bash -u
file="$(cat installs.txt)"
for word in $file; do
  echo $word
done
```

I also changed you back qoutes to `$( )` as this is the recommended way and I think its easier to read too

Comment: thanks. Coming from a JavaScript background mainly and some rails, this syntax is quite strange to me :)

Comment: He was also missing the `$` when using `file` -- I see you fixed that as well.

Comment: Also, whats the -u mean in the shebang? Googled it, but no avail.

Comment: The `-u` means the script will print an error if you reference an unset variable. Very useful for catching typos. e.g. if you accidentally had `echo $wrod` it woulf just print blank lines. But with the `-u` it would print an error message saying `wrod` is an undefined variable